# How to set lightning:input focus on initial render

Tags: lightning-aura-components, rendering

I have a Lightning Aura Component form with several lightning:input elements, and a request to set the cursor/focus to the first input when the component loads.

I have something like this in my component:

```
<aura:attribute name="myDate" type="Date" />
<aura:attribute name="fruitOptions" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="fruitOptionSelection" type="String" />

<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.myDate}" action="{!c.setFruitOptions}" />

<lightning:input aura:id="field" type="date" name="myDate" label="My Date" required="true" 
    value="{!v.myDate}"/>
<aura:if isTrue="{! !empty(v.fruitOptions) }">
    <lightning:radioGroup aura:id="field" name="myFruitPicker" label="Select a fruit" 
        options="{!v.fruitOptions}" value="{!v.fruitOptionSelection}" />
</aura:if>
```

In the controller:

```
onRender : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.setInitFocus(component);
},

setFruitOptions : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.setOptions(component);
},
```

And in the helper:

```
setInitFocus: function(component) {
    var fields = component.find('field');
    Array.isArray(fields) ? fields[0].focus() : fields.focus();
},

setOptions: function(component) {
    var date = new Date(component.get('v.myDate'));
    var newOptions = null;
    if (date < new Date('2018-01-01')) {
        newOptions = [
            {label: 'Apples', value: 'Apples'},
            {label: 'Pears', value: 'Pears'},
            {label: 'Oranges', value: 'Oranges'}
        ];
    } else {
        newOptions = [
            {label: 'Bananas', value: 'Bananas'},
            {label: 'Pineapples', value: 'Pineapples'}
        ];
    }
    component.set('v.myOptions', newOptions);
}
```

This works great in the sense that it focuses the cursor on the "My Date" input on load.  The problem is that it does this again when I supply a value in the My Date field, which triggers the change handler and eventually causes parts of the component to rerender.

I only want it to execute setInitFocus on the initial rendering, not any subsequent ones. Best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems obvious in hindsight, but here's how I solved it.

I added this to the component...

```
<aura:attribute name="renderedOnce" type="Boolean" default="false" />
```

...And changed the controller onRender method like so...

```
onRender : function(component, event, helper) {
    if ( !component.get('v.renderedOnce') ) {
        helper.setInitFocus(component);
        component.set('v.renderedOnce', true);
    }
},
```

I'm still curious if there are ways to extract contextual information out of the render event that could be used in similar scenarios.  If anyone knows anything like that, please share!